# Adding JPanel to JFrame losing ability to organize components - Java

Tags: java, class, object, jframe, jpanel

Description: I have been working on this small project in which I need to send a a specific JPanel from a class to the main JFrame based upon a parameter passed (1-4). In my main class I have a JFrame set up so I can visually check the panel being passed.

> What doesn't work

Inside the "Accessor Class", I cannot seem to position the JComboBox in the middle of the Panel. Additionally, i'm not too sure I can do any kind of positioning. I implemented a button earlier with the exact same code (I replaced the JComboBox) and I couldn't resize the button either. HOWEVER... I can change the color of it.

GridBagLayout should center on default. Why is this being overridden? If you look at the picture/link provided, it shifts itself to the top center. I simply cannot move it.

Is this problem a result of the way I receive the JPanel from the class. Is there perhaps a better way I could call the panel.

Sorry for a lack of clarity. Struggling to comprehend some of the underlying concepts here in Java.

Any help is appreciated.

> This is the main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Accessor accessorOne = new Accessor(1); //Creates the Panel with param 1
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    frame.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
    frame.add(new JButton("Button 3"));
    frame.add(new JButton("Button 4"));
    frame.add(accessorOne); //Adds the Panel to the last spot in the JFrame
    frame.setSize(650, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

> This is the "Accessor" class that defines the panel

```
public class Accessor extends JPanel{

 JPanel panel = new JPanel();

 public Accessor(int num){

    if(num == 1){
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    String[] choice1 = {"Testing One", "Testing two" };
    JComboBox choiceBoxOne = new JComboBox(choice1);
    choiceBoxOne.setBackground(Color.red); //These changes are correctly reflected!
    panel.add(choiceBoxOne);
    choiceBoxOne.setLocation(300,300); //ERROR -> Setting this value changes nothing!
    add(panel);
    } 
    // Other num options
 } 
}
```

[This is the photo of the Jframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T2cs.png)

Comment: After some more testing, it must be the way I call the jpanel from the other class. If I set up the panel directly in the main method all the layouts work correctly.

Comment: Dude, as Accessor class is extending the JPanel, why do you create a JPanel class? you should add the choiceBoxOne to he Accessor class instead of your JPanel object. And also, you should setLayout to the Accessos class, not a JPanel object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are using `panel` within class `Accessor`(also a panel with default layout as FlowLayout). So instead of making another panel instance, you could have just use GridBagLayout to instance of `Accessor` and add controls directly to `Accessor` instead of new `panel`.

Again absolute positioning works with `null` layouts(not recommended).

Also don't forget to use `GridBagConstraints` along with `GridBagLayout`.